# What is the systemd target that is triggered when user logs in?

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I try to migrate from upstart and many of my custom services are triggered when user successfully logs in.

I want to find an equivalent of `start on desktop-session-start` stanza of Ubuntu's upstart. Does anyone can help me?

Comment: @guntbert I am migrating from upstart to systemd. Aren't we all?

Answer (score 1):

OK. I have found it out.

There is no such target. Events post user login are handled by *completely separate* systemd system, the `systemd --user`.

The system is launched by a custom pam module `pam_systemd.so` and stanza in `/etc/pam.d/common_session`.

AFAIU all commands triggered by the `systemd --user` are executed with the user's privileges. If you want to trigger something *just after* user login *as a root* - use `pam`, just like the `systemd` does.